# Webpack unable to load FontAwesome Kit (6.x) via NPM into JS of App?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, font-awesome

I have an app in which I'm trying to load some JS into their own .js files (i.e. bootstrap will be loaded via `bootstrap.hash.js`, fontawesome will be `fontawesome.hash.js`)

I'm using webpack to do this - but am struggling with fontawesome and their kits specifically (I have a pro subscription). I can load fontawesome via CSS/Fonts no problem - but wanted to use some of the other features available only to JS+SVGs (like layering and masking).

I can load fontawesome pro, it works great. Locally I can have webpack load up the `all.min.js` and it puts it in the `fontawesome.hash.js` for me - but I need to do that with the kit as it has custom icons that I have added.

This is an example of a *working* `webpack.config.js` that loads fontawesome into it's own `.js` file and puts it in my template:

```
const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require("css-minimizer-webpack-plugin");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
//const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

module.exports = {
    mode: "production",
    entry: {
        vendor: "./static/myapp/src/js/vendor.js",
        fontawesome: "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/js/all.min.js",
        main: "./static/myapp/src/js/main.js",
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].[contenthash].js",
        path: path.join(__dirname, "static/myapp/dist/js/"),
        publicPath: "/static/myapp/dist/js/",
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
            new TerserPlugin(),
        ],
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                bootstrapCss: {
                    name: 'bootstrap',
                    test: /bootstrap\.scss$/,
                    chunks: 'all',
                    enforce: true,
                },
                // fontawesomeCss: {
                //     name: 'fontawesome',
                //     test: /fontawesome\.scss$/,
                //     chunks: 'all',
                //     enforce: true,
                // },
                fontawesomeJs: {
                        name: 'fontawesome',
                        test: /[\\/]@fortawesome[\\/]fontawesome-pro[\\/]js[\\/]all\.min\.js$/,
                        chunks: 'all',
                        enforce: true,
                    },
            },
        },
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(scss)$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {sourceMap: true}
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "postcss-loader",
                        options: {postcssOptions: {plugins: [autoprefixer()]}}
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            sassOptions: {
                                includePaths: ['./static/myapp/src/css'],
                            },
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                type: 'asset/resource',
                generator: {
                    filename: 'fonts/[name][hash].[ext]',
                },

            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        //new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '../css/[name].[contenthash].css',
            chunkFilename: '../css/[name].[contenthash].css',
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: path.join(
                __dirname,
                "static/myapp/src/html/webpack_bundles.html"
            ),
            filename: path.join(
                __dirname,
                "templates/myapp/webpack_bundles.html"
            ),
            // Use our template to control placement of the bundles
            inject: false,
            chunks: ['bootstrap', 'fontawesome', 'vendor', 'main'],
            chunksSortMode: 'manual',
            scriptLoading: "blocking",
        }),
    ],
};
```

Here is a non-working `webpack.config.js` where I try to load my kit (which is installed via npm):

```
const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require("css-minimizer-webpack-plugin");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
//const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

module.exports = {
    mode: "production",
    entry: {
        vendor: "./static/myapp/src/js/vendor.js",
        fontawesome: "@awesome.me/kit-123456abc/icons/js/all.min.js",
        main: "./static/myapp/src/js/main.js",
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].[contenthash].js",
        path: path.join(__dirname, "static/myapp/dist/js/"),
        publicPath: "/static/myapp/dist/js/",
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
            new TerserPlugin(),
        ],
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                bootstrapCss: {
                    name: 'bootstrap',
                    test: /bootstrap\.scss$/,
                    chunks: 'all',
                    enforce: true,
                },
                // fontawesomeCss: {
                //     name: 'fontawesome',
                //     test: /fontawesome\.scss$/,
                //     chunks: 'all',
                //     enforce: true,
                // },
                fontawesomeJs: {
                        name: 'fontawesome',
                        test: /[\\/]@awesome\.me[\\/]kit-123456abc[\\/]icons[\\/]js[\\/]all\.min\.js$/,
                        chunks: 'all',
                        enforce: true,
                    },
            },
        },
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(scss)$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {sourceMap: true}
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "postcss-loader",
                        options: {postcssOptions: {plugins: [autoprefixer()]}}
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            sassOptions: {
                                includePaths: ['./static/myapp/src/css'],
                            },
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                type: 'asset/resource',
                generator: {
                    filename: 'fonts/[name][hash].[ext]',
                },

            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        //new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '../css/[name].[contenthash].css',
            chunkFilename: '../css/[name].[contenthash].css',
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: path.join(
                __dirname,
                "static/myapp/src/html/webpack_bundles.html"
            ),
            filename: path.join(
                __dirname,
                "templates/myapp/webpack_bundles.html"
            ),
            // Use our template to control placement of the bundles
            inject: false,
            chunks: ['bootstrap', 'fontawesome', 'vendor', 'main'],
            chunksSortMode: 'manual',
            scriptLoading: "blocking",
        }),
    ],
};
```

However that gives me this error:

```
ERROR in fontawesome
Module not found: Error: Package path ./icons/js/all.min.js is not exported from package /Users/me/project/myapp/node_modules/@awesome.me/kit-123456abc (see exports field in /Users/me/project/myapp/node_modules/@awesome.me/kit-123456abc/package.json)
```

I can see the file if I open my node_module directory and navigate to it.

If I open the `package.json` it says in the error I see these relevant parts:

```
    // Other similar stuff before this

    "./icons/sharp/solid": {
      "types": "./icons/modules/sharp/solid.d.ts",
      "import": "./icons/modules/sharp/solid.mjs",
      "require": "./icons/modules/sharp/solid.js",
      "default": "./icons/modules/sharp/solid.js"
    },
    
    "./icons/sharp/thin": {
      "types": "./icons/modules/sharp/thin.d.ts",
      "import": "./icons/modules/sharp/thin.mjs",
      "require": "./icons/modules/sharp/thin.js",
      "default": "./icons/modules/sharp/thin.js"
    },
    
    
    "./icons/kit/custom": {
      "types": "./icons/modules/kit/custom.d.ts",
      "import": "./icons/modules/kit/custom.mjs",
      "require": "./icons/modules/kit/custom.js",
      "default": "./icons/modules/kit/custom.js"
    },
    
    "./icons/css/*.css": {
      "default": "./icons/css/*.css"
    },
    "./icons/less/*.less": {
      "default": "./icons/less/*.less"
    },
    "./icons/scss/*.scss": {
      "default": "./icons/scss/*.scss"
    },

    // Other stuff after this
```

So I changed my webpack to include what I thought might be the appropriate thing:

```
entry: {
   // ...
   fontawesome: ["@awesome.me/kit-123456abc/icons/classic/solid", "@awesome.me/kit-123456abc/icons/kit/custom"],
   // ...
},
```

It builds the `fontawesome.hash.js` file and inserts it into my html - but the file is empty.

The file only contains:

```
(()=>{"use strict"})();
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated!